# Как правильно называть имена классов в Java?

Tags: java, android, android-fragment

Как правильно называть имена классов в Java?

Есть у меня к примеру список классов. Удобнее читать так?

```
FragmentInternalCapitalization
FragmentWordsRunTogether
FragmentWordsStrungTogether
FragmentCamelHumpedWord
FragmentInternalCapitalization
FragmentWordsRunTogether
FragmentWordsStrungTogether
FragmentCamelHumpedWord
```

Или все так так?

```
InternalCapitalizationFragment
WordsRunTogetherFragment
WordsStrungTogetherFragment
CamelHumpedWordFragment
InternalCapitalizationFragment
WordsRunTogetherFragment
WordsStrungTogetherFragment
CamelHumpedWordFragment
```

Половина кода у меня так половина так)).  Это чем то похоже на

`Strings str[]` и `Strings []str`

Конечно для коротких названий без разницы. А если названия будут из 3-5 слов.

Только не пишите как хочешь). А то ведь если так то я и так могу называть классы

`OneTwoFragmentThreeFour` =)

Просто в iOS к примеру там все названия классов идут с переди. Типо `NSString` `NSlalal`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Надо оттолкнуться от первоисточника, а именно [Google Java Style Guide](https://google.github.io/styleguide/javaguide.html) - именование Android'а следуют именно этому гайду.

Про именование классов написано буквально следующее:

> Class names are written in UpperCamelCase.
>   Class names are typically nouns or noun phrases. For example, Character or ImmutableList. Interface names may also be nouns or noun phrases (for example, List), but may sometimes be adjectives or adjective phrases instead (for example, Readable).

Смысл этой белиберды состоит в том, что именование классов обычно состоит из существительных (иногда прилагательных) образующих или слова или фразу в виде [CamelCase](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/CamelCase)

Возвращаясь к вопросу, ни один из представленных вариантов (на мой английский) не удовлетворяет критериям  *фразы*, посему я бы таки рассмотрел такие варианты:

```
FirstFragment
SecondFragment
ThirdFragment
FourthFragment
```

Comment: Не думаю, что автор в самом деле собирается именовать свои классы, как `OneFragment`, а не осмысленными именами, соответствующими их назначению, иначе это было бы очень не разумно.

Comment: @pavlofff, обновил вопрос с обновленными названиями. теперь они не бесмысленные

Comment: @EraNewGames правильный по прежнему второй вариант с классом-родителем в конце

Comment: @pavlofff а как же `ViewHolder` - его именование не соответствует вашей логике

Comment: `ViewHolder` не наследник класса `View`, если вы об этом, это паттерн холдер, который хранит вьюшки, как вы и сами знаете, не вижу противоречий "моей" (на самом деле общепринятой в андроид-разработке) логики :)

Answer (score 8):

Стиль, как `FragmentOne` кажется удобнее тем, что в списке файлов классы будут сгруппированы по принадлежности, то есть сначала идут все активити, потом фрагменты и тд, так их удобнее искать в дереве проекта, если таких файлов достаточное количество. Однако, на самом деле, в поиске класса по имени не первостепенно важно, кто его родитель, более важно предназначение, которое выражается через собственное осмысленное имя. Если появляется необходимость в группировке по другому признаку, то обычно это делается через поддиректории в основной директории с кодом, как *src/../service* (то есть выделение в пакет), как в эталонном [приложении Google I/O Sched](https://github.com/google/iosched/tree/master/lib/src/main/java/com/google/samples/apps/iosched)

Для расширяющих классов принято писать имя родительского класса в конце, как `AppCompatActivity`, `ListFragment` и тд.

С точки зрения стиля Android правильным будет второй вариант

Comment: А вы как используете?)

Comment: @EraNewGames Второй вариант, естественно

Comment: @EraNewGames немного расширил ответ и причины

Answer (score 1):

[Придерживаться единого стиля и смысловой нагрузки](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25167231/word-order-in-class-names-in-java)
В Вашем случае FragmentOne - фрагмент один, OneFragment - один фрагмент, поэтому FragmentOne будет логичнее.

Comment: Тут дело не в логичности. А в том как удобно читать.
Напишите в блокноте 20 имен классов от 4-6 слов. И в конце поставте Fragment. Затем наоборот и вы увидите что 1 вариант лучше, так как вы сразу видите название и смысл класса.

Хотя в книгах которые я читал говорится о том что и вы сказали.

Comment: А зачем столько классов в 1 пакете? Имена классов могут повторятся, но находится в разных, логически разделенных пакетах

Comment: Вы когда - нибудь большие проекты писали? видимо нет. Создавая много пакетов вы от проблемы не уйдете.